# Why should derangements be applicable to this question of parked cars?

Tags: combinatorics

Seven people go to a cinema and park their cars outside, which are identical. While returning only three of them are able to unlock their cars (assuming that a car can only be unlocked by its own key). Total number of ways in which this can be done is?

So out of 7 cars, choosing 3 is $\binom{7}{3}$. But when I searched this question up on the internet, every site showed that we need to use derangement here. My question is why? Isn't $\binom{7}{3}$ the only way to choose 3 cars out of 7?

Why should there be anything more to the question?

Comment: I don't get the question in the first place ... if the cars are identical, shouldn't their locks be identical as well, and hence their keys?  I guess the assumption is they just look the same in terms of make, model, and color ... but even if so, did they forget where they parked their car ... or did someone somehow just rearrange those cars?  And why didn't they just try the other cars with their key? As a real-life scenario this all makes little sense to me ...

Comment: This seems to be a question of "What do you want to count?"  Do you consider each possible outcome to be described exclusively by which three of the seven people successfully unlocked their car?  Do you instead want to consider as each possible outcome the ways in which the seven people all selected which car to unlock such that three of them succeeded?  If so, we need to clarify further how the people come out and choose the cars... can more than one person choose the same car?  Do they only get one choice and do they get to see other people's attempts and success/failure before choosing?

Comment: @Bram28 I don't see the problem.  Obviously when they try putting a key in the wrong car, it immediately drops the car and the person into an endless pit, never to be seen again.  If only they had asked the right question to the knights and knaves at the entrance!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah, yes, of course ... those evil knights and knaves again! I should have realized that! :)

Comment: If you consider the outcome where persons 1,2,3 all correctly picked their original cars 1,2,3 while persons 4,5,6,7 each tried cars 5,6,7,4 respectively (person 4 tried car 5, person 5 tried car 6, etc...) to be a different outcome than where instead persons 4,5,6,7 each tried cars 7,6,5,4 respectively instead, then considering only $\binom{7}{3}$ does not encapsulate any of that information while using derangements might.

Comment: @JMoravitz Understood, wasn't taking arrangements of the cars into consideration, now finally got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$7 \choose 3$ is the number of ways to pick the $3$ cars whose owners were able to open ... and thus also the number of ways to pick the $4$ remaining cars that they weren't able to open.  But I suppose the question is asking: in how many could those cars have been switched? That is, if the $4$ cars are labeled $ABCD$, and were originally parked in that order, in how many ways can we swap the cars so that none of them are in that original location?  So, $BDAC$ would be one of those ways, but $CADB$ would be another .... and to find all the ways, you need derangements. So, you need to multiply $7 \choose 3$ (or $7 \choose 4$) by the number of derangements for $4$ objects.

Comment: Oh so the arrangement of the car needs to be changed so that none of the cars( except the 3 which were able to be unlocked) are in their original positions? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes, that's it!

Comment: @Techie5879 Or: $4$ of the owners forgot where they parked their car, and tried the wrong car (but each owner did try a different car) ... this leads of course to the same calculation ... but is a little more plausible as a real life situation ...